# Prevent US buyers from checking out in Canadian Dollars (only US dollars)

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

My store has two currencies, US dollars and Canadian dollars. Base currency is Canadian dollars, US dollars is just a conversion. But I have an extension which allows customer to checkout in the currency they wish (CAD or USD) and the credit card will be charged in the respective currency.

Is there a way to prevent US buyers from checking out using Canadian dollars ?

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: You will need to provide the name of the extension you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an extension that only allows them to checkout in the currency of their region.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-currency-switcher-1.html